# Calendar returning duplicate lines per employee

Tags: reporting-services, calendar

I have created a simple table in SSRS that has employees down the left hand side and each column is a number 1 - 31. When an employee books a holiday it puts an X in the dates they are on holiday using an if function if the day is between a date from and date to column.

This works fine but when there is more than one holiday booked in the month then the employee will have duplicate lines rather than it going along the same line in the table. When adding in the group function it only shows the first holiday they booked in the month. Is it possible to show all lines in one?

Here's my SQL:

```sql
SELECT *
    ,firstname + ' ' + lastname AS 'full'
    ,datediff(d, holidaystart, holidayend) AS 'days'
    ,DAY(DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, holidaystart) + 1, 0))) AS LastDay
FROM dbo.holdates
WHERE Month(holidaystart) = Param1
    AND holyear = '8'
    AND holidaystat = 'Approved'
    AND location = ISNULL(Param2, location)
    AND (holyear = @Param3 - 2005)
    OR Month(holidayend) = Param1
    AND (holyear = Param3 - 2005)
    AND holidaystat = 'Approved'
    AND location = ISNULL(Param2, location)
ORDER BY (firstname + ' ' + lastname)
```

Comment: Certainly possible, but currently impossible to definitely answer your question. You should share with us what your dataset looks like, and what the structure of your report and controls is.

Comment: SELECT *, firstname + ' ' +  lastname as 'full', datediff(d,holidaystart, holidayend) as 'days', DAY(DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,holidaystart)+1,0))) as LastDay
FROM dbo.holdates
WHERE Month(holidaystart) = Param1 AND holyear = '8' AND holidaystat= 'Approved' AND location =ISNULL (Param2,location) AND (holyear =@Param3 -2005) OR Month(holidayend) = Param1 AND (holyear =Param3 -2005) AND holidaystat= 'Approved' AND location =ISNULL (Param2,location)
ORDER BY (firstname + ' ' +  lastname)

Comment: :-) forgot to mention, Stack Overflow is different from other forums... you're allowed to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16219035/edit) your own (and other's) questions to improve them using the "edit" link below the post. Feel free to edit your question and add more detail (you have many [formatting options](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the question for your SQL code). If your edits are substantial, your question's also bumped to the front page again, increasing chances of someone providing an answer!

Answer (score 0):

This gets easier if you generate the range of dates you want to report about with a CTE, and then join that to the actual holiday dates. The CTE would look something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @fromDate DATE = '20130701',
        @toDate DATE = '20130801';

WITH dates
AS (    SELECT @fromDate "date"

        UNION ALL

        SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, "date")
        FROM dates
        WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, "date") <= @toDate
    )
-- Continued below...
```

Then select your data against this CTE as such:

```sql
SELECT dates."date"
      ,CASE WHEN h.holidaystart IS NOT NULL THEN 'X' ELSE NULL END AS HasHoliday
      ,firstname + ' ' + lastname AS "full"
      ,datediff(d, holidaystart, holidayend) AS "days"
FROM dates
     LEFT JOIN @holdates h ON dates."date" BETWEEN h.holidaystart AND h.holidayend
WHERE Month(holidaystart) = Param1
    AND h.holyear = '8'
    AND h.holidaystat = 'Approved'
    AND h.location = ISNULL(Param2, location)
ORDER BY (firstname + ' ' + lastname)
```

This will give a result set along these lines:

```
date            HasHoliday  full
--------------- ----------- ---------
2013-07-01      NULL        NULL
2013-07-02      NULL        NULL
2013-07-03      NULL        NULL
2013-07-04      NULL        NULL
2013-07-05      X           John
2013-07-05      X           Mark
2013-07-06      X           John
2013-07-06      X           Mark
2013-07-07      X           John
etc.
```

Now in SSRS, all you need to do is add a matrix where you:

- group rows day of month
- group columns based on month (if needed) and then on person
- use the `HasHoliday` value in cells

In any case, the above dataset is a much more convenient basis for creating calendar-like reports.